# .htacces rewrite url is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been searching for 2 days now and haven't found a complete solution to this problem.

my directories (on localhost):
root
 - fons (here is my **htaccess** file located)
 - - functions (some functions)
 - - web (index.php)
 - - docs (index.php)
 - - user (index.php)

I'd like to have when i go to localhost/fons/ , that i see the content of the web map but the url should remain localhost/fons. If i go to localhost/fons/docs/ then i see the docs content , and localhost/fons/user/ -> user content

the .htaccess i've written:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(fons/user|fons/docs)
RewriteRule ^$ /fons/web
```

With this htaccess when i go to localhost/fons/ i get redirected to the web-subfolder and the url changes.

What do i have to change so that the url stays the same, but i see the content of the web folder?

and if possible, is there a way to ditch the 'fons' in htaccess, so in the future when i create another project with the same structure, i can just copy paste the htaccess and don't need to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use RewriteBase to eliminate /fons like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /fons
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(user|docs)
RewriteRule ^$ /web [NC]
```

Also from experience, the rewriterule shouldn't actually forwarded to the new url in the browser url bar unless you have a [R] flag set. I added the [NC] (case insensitive flag) to explicitly state no [R] flag. If it's doing it, can you provide a link to test further?

Comment: I will put it online in about 5 hours. With that in my htaccess, i get a 404 object not found. (because there is no index file where the htaccess is. So no rewrite/redirect)